# Define and then call template function inside constructor of its own template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use a template function inside **its own template class**. How do we declare and call this function? Here's a stab at what I think is the correct code, deliberately doesn't achieve anything for illustration purposes:

```
template<typename T> class TEMPLATE_CLASS
{
    // The template constructor
    TEMPLATE_CLASS(T value)
    { 
        // Here I call the class's template member function
        // ... but fails
        T variable = setVariable(value);
    }

    template<typename U>
    T setVariable(T value_to_set)
    {
        return value_to_set;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, when you pass a `T` to the function, the compiler cannot figure out what `U` should be. Usually the template type is used for one of the parameters, and the compiler can then deduce the type from there.

You *could* use `setVariable<int>(value)` to indicate that `U` is supposed to be `int`, but from the small example it is hard to tell it that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no point of making this method a template method because you don't use `U` anywhere inside her scope. But still if you wan't it this way your code should look like this:

```
template<typename T> class TEMPLATE_CLASS
{
    // The template constructor
    TEMPLATE_CLASS(T value)
    { 
        // Here I call the class's template member function
        // ... but fails
        T variable = setVariable(value);
    }

    template<typename U>
    U setVariable(U value_to_set)
    {
       return value_to_set;
    }
}
```

Depending on situation if you wan't to do anything with `value_to_set` inside method e.g. casting to `T` you can return `T` from it.